# Microsoft-Cognitive: Emotion API in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, azure-cognitive-services

I get the response below after making a call to the emotion api.

```
{
  "FaceRectangle": {
    "Top": 141,
    "Left": 331,
    "Width": 52,
    "Height": 52
  },
  "Scores": {
    "Anger": 0.002451766,
    "Contempt": 0.0005512201,
    "Disgust": 0.0063303886,
    "Fear": 0.000122375583,
    "Happiness": 0.9589189,
    "Neutral": 0.0222537462,
    "Sadness": 0.008983561,
    "Surprise": 0.000388026354
  }
}
```

How can I create a variable to hold just the score of happiness? Below is the python code:

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64, sys
headers = {
  key.
  'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
  'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '************************',
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({


    })
body = open('my_image.jpg','rb').read()
try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognize?%s" % params, body, headers)

    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)

    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e.args)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
import json
dump = json.dumps(data)
json_string = json.loads(dump)
happiness =  str(json_string[0]['Scores']['Happiness'])
```

Comment: i get this error >> "'int' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: `data` is already a string.  So you should skip the `json.dumps` call and just do a `json.loads`.  Also skip the `str` call seem if you want a numeric value.

Answer (score -1):

```
import ast

data = response.read()
b = data.decode("utf-8") #bytes to string conversion
c = ast.literal_eval(b) #string to list conversion
print(c[0]['scores']['happiness']) #parsing
```